# What's the easiest way to show a Windows Explorer-type file structure in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I thought I'd ask in case someone else has run into this before.

How would you go about showing the user's file directory structure in a Java applet, something like Windows Explorer?

Would I have to create a JTree and manipulate that, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a [FileChooser](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html). Your applet needs to be a signed applet so it could access the client file system, here a [small article](http://faq.javaranch.com/view?HowCanAnAppletReadFilesOnTheLocalFileSystem) regarding this

Answer (score 1):

I think [JTree](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/FileTree.htm) would be the easiest way.

but if you just want it to view files before you load them then use a [file chooser](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

Comment: your JTree link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/FileTree.htm no more alive. Could you post anything new?